# Windows desktop to UWP conversion - application w. Python executable, .NET services, tools, using nginx, ffmpeg, etc

Tags: uwp, windows-10-universal, windows-8.1-universal

I have a native Windows desktop 'application' that consists of

- a Python compiled executable
- several .NET applications and services
- C++ Win32 application and dlls using sockets, libraries like libuv etc.
- There's network access, sockets, some tools require one-time rights elevation (UAC)
- dependencies with nginx, ffmpeg, etc. (installed together as *part of*)

all installed with Advanced Installer as one 'application' (to the user it is one application, but it contains several executables / modules / dependencies - subinstallers).

How can I convert this to the Universal Windows Platform (UWP) in the form of one `appx` package targeting Windows 8.1 and 10 desktop, is it possible at all?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you will have to rebuild and rearchitecture your application complete since services are not working, UAC is not allowed and for the dependencies you have to figure out if their are compatible with UWP.

if your goal is just to make your app available from the windows store you can check out the desktop bridge; https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/bridges/desktop this will wrap your app in an appx that can be run on the windows 10 Anniversary update. But still you will need do to some work since services are not supported.

Comment: Thanks. I just found [this Microsoft how-to: 'Create and consume an app service'](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/launch-resume/how-to-create-and-consume-an-app-service) saying services are now possible with Windows 10, version 1607. What do you think?

Comment: That url says about the WinRT "App Service", it's totally different concept from Win32 "System Services".

Comment: I assumed I could convert my Win32 service using [the Desktop Bridge](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/porting/desktop-to-uwp-root?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396). Desktop Bridge doesn't 'do' services?

Comment: nope win32 services are not supported by the desktop bridge. this part you really have to rearchitecture. appservices and background tasks will be something you can check out

Answer (score 1):

Just as Dave mentioned, you need some work around the app. Desktop Bridge does not support any machine resources (i.e. services, drivers, access to HKLM, etc...)

As you probably know, [Advanced Installer can also help you package your UWP app](http://www.advancedinstaller.com/uwp-app-package.html), once it is fully compatible.

For advices on converting your service and others issues I recommend [this Microsoft forum](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsapps/en-US/home?forum=wpdevelop&brandIgnore=True&sort=relevancedesc&searchTerm=service%20win32).

Comment: Well, besides Desktop Bridge there's also the [Desktop App Converter (DAC)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/porting/desktop-to-uwp-run-desktop-app-converter) and there's even [a walkthrough that converts powerful video player VLC Player](http://www.howtogeek.com/250041/how-to-convert-a-windows-desktop-app-to-a-universal-windows-app/) to a UWP app. It does some more advanced virtualization stuff and there's caveats though.